# I am unable to read data from get storage in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, backend, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to save data in local storage by using get storage. I created a instance of get storage (box) and write data in it in our services screen.
[Here I created a instance of get storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CgtG.png)

[Here I write data in box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxweU.png)
So I am trying to read this data from another screen of project but a error occur.
[Here box can not be recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POTFZ.png)

Please give your solutions Please.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the codes and format them so they are more readable than images.

Answer (score 0):

to read data from get storage you need to use `box.read(key)`:

> in your case if you want to read **Name**:

```
var name = box.read('Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way.

```dart
final box = GetStorage();
box.write('name', 'John');
```

or

```dart
GetStorage().write('name', 'John');
```

You can read this way.

```dart
final box = GetStorage();
String name = box.read('name');
```

or

```dart
String name = GetStorage().read('name');
```

Remember: you must initialize get storage before using it.

```
void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

For more details you can visit documentation [here](https://tabpole.github.io/get-storage)